# How to make the day dynamic for Current month and year in PHP

Tags: php

Here is the code below:

```
<?php 
 $dateValue= date("Y-m-15");
?>
```

I want the day(15) to be any integer from 1 to 30.Please help my out.

Comment: Your code works fine to me. [See this fiddle](http://ideone.com/RLxJ5P). I don't understand your question. Please post more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want day without leading zeros then use `j`

```
 $dateValue= date("Y-m-j");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php